# Is there a way to enable allow-forms on the Live App's iframe?

Tags: quip, liveapps

I'm building a live app with Salesforce integration, that can't save its changes because the form submission is blocked with the following error: 
`Blocked form submission to https://... because the form's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-forms' permission is not set`

Is there a way to enable form-submissions in Live Apps?

Answer (score 0):

You're right that this is locked down via Quip at the CSP level. We do grant some apps (conditionally, case by case) this permission following a security review.